# Convert DateTime field token to local time zone in email rule

Tags: orchardcms

Within Orchard I have a custom content type that includes a DateTime field. I've created a rule to send an email when a new content item is submitted. I'm able to include the value of the DateTime field in the email using the following token:

```
{Content.Fields.MyContentType.MyDateTimeField}
```

The problem I'm running into is that the date/time value that replaces the token is in UTC and I need it to be in the timezone configured for my Orchard instance.

I see there's a token for the current date/time that looks like this:

```
{Date.Local}
```

But .Local does not seem to be valid on the DateTime field token.

It looks like it wouldn't be too hard to create a custom token provider to solve for this but before I did that I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing an easier, existing solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date token does indeed have a `Local` subtoken but the problem here is that `{Content.Fields.MyContentType.MyDateTimeField}` is not a date token, it's still just the field. You need to get its actual value. If you look at `FieldTokens.cs`, you'll see that the date field token has a `DateTime` token. So `{Content.Fields.MyContentType.MyDateTimeField.DateTime.Local}` should do the trick I think.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Makes total sense now too. Thanks

Comment: I found that in older versions of Orchard (1.4 in my case) the date token is accessed through Date instead of DateTime so the full token would be {Content.Fields.MyContentType.MyDateTimeField.Date.Local}. Just wanted to throw that out there in case anyone runs into it.