# Format a Date Time to the Full date/time pattern (short time) in Orchard

Tags: formatting, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Within Orchard CMS (version 1.6) I have a Query that displays a DateTime property called StartDate. When setting it up I chose the "Full date/time pattern (short time)" as the Date format, and then I was rewriting the output as follows:

```
<My html text here> {Text}
```

This would render as "My html text here **Saturday, April 13, 2013 2:30 PM**".

I realized that for users on a different time zone, the date/time was being converted automatically and instead of displaying 2:30 PM (server is at PST), it was displaying 5:30 PM (user was at EST).

Following [Bertrand Le Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363821/bertrand-le-roy)'s solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386048/convert-datetime-field-token-to-local-time-zone-in-email-rule), it worked out nice with one minor issue.

Now my code is this:

```
<My html text here> {Content.Fields.MyContentType.MyDateTimeField.DateTime.Local}
```

And here is the result: "My html text here **4/13/2013 2:30:00 PM**".

The formatting is not the one I would rather use.

Does anyone know how can I format this to the Full date/time pattern (short time)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{Content.Fields.MyContentType.MyDateTimeField.DateTime.Local.Format:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt}` should do the trick.